# Using Crashlytics on iOS with CMake

Tags: cmake, google-fabric

Our projects all use CMake, and Fabric seems to require a script run in XCode's build environment to extract information. CMake doesn't seem to have a way to add a run script build phase.

So, I tried running the script manually after setting the following manually from known values in CMake:

```
INFOPLIST_PATH
BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR
DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME
DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH
PROJECT_DIR
```

As a result, there were no errors when running the script but ..also nothing happened. I just got a "Launching uploader in validation mode" and then the process exited.

Is it possible I could get a full run-down of what the program needs in order to run? Our projects are built on a build server so having to VNC in and launch xcode to build is not really an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using CMake, instead of using the run script build phase, I'd use the [upload-symbols](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script) script as that will be a more reliable way to upload the dSYMs to Crashlytics.

Comment: That doesn't seem to exist in the iOS package.

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods or did you install the frameworks manually or via the app? `upload-symbols` isn't available in the pods but you can access it if you download the Fabric app: https://www.fabric.io/downloads/apple

Comment: Doing it manually. There is no upload-symbols in the iOS frameworks (Fabric nor Crashlytics). There is uploadDSYM which is what's being called from the run script in Crashlytics framework, or also "submit" in the Fabric framework.

I did download and try the OSX package's upload-symbols and it seemed to upload, but the app doesn't show up in the list.

Edit: Sorry I completely misunderstood. Everything's working now, thanks for your help.